# Google Chrome change Local Backend Path

Tags: google-chrome

I searched everywhere on google how to change for Google Chrome browser the Local Backend Path and I could only find one solution with the GPO.

The problem I have is that in my GPOs, I don't have that Policy. Could it be that the GPO's are only for Google Chrome Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by searching Google Chrome enterprise, downloaded the bundle and added the admx/adm templates into my windows.

And from there I could find `Set roaming local data directory`.